# "Dimension sizes are not equal and destination array is not flexible."

Tags: arrays, vector, modelica, dimension

When I call this function from my "main model" it produces the expected result, but when I call it from a different function, saving, "testing" and compilation works fine, but upon "simulation" I get the following error message: *"Dimension sizes are not equal and destination array is not flexible"*

The function reverses/"flips" a vector of length n, so that last element comes first.

```
function myReverse
  input Integer n; 
  input Real[n] v; //  "Real vector";
  output Real[n] result; // "Elements of vector v in reversed order";

algorithm

  result := vector({v[end - i + 1] for i in 1:n});

end myReverse;
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a full example. Your code looks fine, except that the `vector()` operator is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

This is strange. I assume you are not using Dymola, because the code you provided works in Dymola 2021x.

I used the following test, simulating the model "Test":

```
package ReversePackage
  function myReverse
    input Real[n] v;       //  "Real vector";
    output Real[n] result; // "Elements of vector v in reversed order";

  protected 
    Integer n=size(v,1);

  algorithm 
    result := vector({v[end - i + 1] for i in 1:n});

  end myReverse;

  model Test
    extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
    Real out[2];

  equation 
    out =ReversePackage.myReverse({time,1});
  end Test;
end ReversePackage;
```

As an additional note: I simplified `myReverse` a bit by reading the size of the input-vector instead of having the size as a parameter that is passed to the function.

Just a "wild guess", but I could imagine, that the `end` operator causes the issue, try replacing it by `n`, which shouldn't be an issue as you have it anyway. Also unecessary `vector()` could cause issues as marco pointed out. So try to remove it as well. Both changes implemented below:

```
function myReverse
  input Real[n] v;       //  "Real vector";
  output Real[n] result; // "Elements of vector v in reversed order";
 
protected 
  Integer n=size(v,1);

algorithm 
  result := {v[n- i + 1] for i in 1:n};

end myReverse;
```

Comment: Markus, I think it is somewhere here that my programming creates problems, I pass the vector size (as I understand it, modelica needs to know vector/array size a priori) as an input .

Comment: Marcus, when I try to run your code "ReversePackage" above, Openmodelica editor crashes. Do you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: I would try to again add `n` as an input, as you did in your original code. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of experience with OpenModelia, so I would suggest to add the OpenModelica tag to the question. There are couple of people on stackoverflow with very good knowledge on OpenModelica...